# Is there a ffs() equivalent for std::bitset?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitset

I want to find the index of the first set bit in a bitset. Most modern CPU's can make use of the FFS instruction to speed this up on normal sized numerical types. Can I make use of this instruction when I want to find the first set bit in a C++ std::bitset?

Comment: How big of a bitset?

Comment: @NathanOliver In my case 256 bits

Comment: Dang.  If it was 64 or smaller I would suggest getting a `unsigned long long` from it and running `ffs` but that won't work here.  There is nothing in the standard so you'll need some sort of custom solution.

Comment: If you can use boost, its `dynamic_bitset` library has a `find_first()` method.

Comment: @Shawn that'll still be expensive due to the dynamic nature. In case of a fixed 256-bit bitset then probably implement a class having four `uint64_t`s would be better

Comment: @phuclv That's basically how it works though; an array of integers.

Comment: It calls an internal `lowest_bit()` function on the first non-0 element of a vector. Not sure how optimized that function is, though. Didn't dig that far into the source.

Comment: @Shawn but it's dynamic and you need a loop as well as many conditions to work out. With a fixed array loop unrolling can be done much more efficiently

Comment: @pbuclv You still have to check to see if each element is 0 or not. There's no real significant difference.

Answer (score -1):

The goal here is to write clear code such that the optimizer recognises the operation. It probably knows about `ffs` and when to use it.

A fixed-size array helps, it gives constants in the loop which facilitates unrolling. Alignment also looks in your favour.

Comment: What actually works? None of [these](https://godbolt.org/z/3uimiJ) did, even using `ffsll` was non-trivial